# Cassandra adding node : opscenter agent not connected

Tags: cluster-computing, cassandra-2.0

I am using Datastax community edition in two windows PCs(64 bit and 32 bit respectively). After setting the initial configuration in cassandra.yaml, in the Opscenter web interface its showing that "1 of 2 agents connected" and recommending to install opscenter agent.
**Node 1(ip: X.X.X.X) Configuration:**
Cluster name : Test Center
seeds : Y.Y.Y.Y
listen address :
rpc_address : 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
num_tokens: 256
**Node 2(ip: Y.Y.Y.Y) Configuration:**
Cluster name : Test Center
seeds : X.X.X.X
listen address :
rpc_address : 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
num_tokens: 256
By default *auto_bootstrap* attribute was absent so I didn't add that and as per instruction I first stopped the services and after changing this setting I started them.
Q1. Any settings I'm missing ?
Thanks for kindly help.
Edited : From X.X.X.X node, the status of Y.Y.Y.Y node [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the datastax-agents so they know what machine OpsCenter is running on.

To do this you will need to edit the following line in address.yaml located in C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\agent\conf.

stomp_interface:

If X.X.X.X is your opscenterd machine:

set stomp_interface: X.X.X.X for all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have made a mistake with the seeds. If these 2 nodes are part of the same cluster (and you've indicated that they both have same name "Test Center", then the seeds should be the same, not different. Set seeds: Y.Y.Y.Y in both nodes. Shutdown both nodes. Start node 1, after it is up then start Node 2. Node 2 will get its settings from the seed (Node 1).
2. listen_address: shouldn't be blank. set it to the ip address of the interface that the node will be listening on. I am assuming these are physical machines.

Comment: Changed as you recommended. Yet its not working. Any more suggestion ?

Comment: Edit made. Still facing that "1 of 2 agents are connected"

Comment: make sure the firewall has the ports open. opscenter uses port 61620 and 61621 to talk to the agents. check opscenterd.conf and address.yaml files to see if ssl is enabled. I would disable ssl and try to get opscenter working before enabling.